# How to fill previous record

Tags: sql

I have the following data in a table i.e. No, Date and Step

```
+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|   No    |                       Date |            Step            |
+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 643995G | 03/12/2012 3:22:48 PM      | TransferInStart            |
| 643995G | 03/12/2012 3:22:50 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 15/02/2013 10:53:57 AM     | Hold                       |
| 643995G | 15/02/2013 10:54:00 AM     | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 20/02/2013 4:38:26 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 21/02/2013 3:27:01 PM      | ExceptionStart             |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 9:38:32 AM      | ExceptionEnd               |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 9:39:32 AM      |                            |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 10:04:53 AM     |                            |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 10:04:56 AM     |                            |
| 643995G | 25/02/2013 10:48:18 AM     | TransferIn                 |
| 643995G | 25/02/2013 10:48:19 AM     | CatalougingStart           |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 1:59:44 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 1:59:45 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 2:05:01 PM      | Catalouging                |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 2:05:02 PM      | ProcessingStart            |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 6:09:51 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 6:09:52 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 04/03/2013 2:03:16 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 04/03/2013 2:03:17 PM      | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 11/03/2013 2:27:14 PM      |                            |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:09:55 AM     | ExceptionStart             |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:10:27 AM     | ExceptionEnd               |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:10:52 AM     |                            |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:11:27 AM     |                            |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:28:37 AM     |                            |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:46:21 AM     | Processing                 |
+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Would like to fill in the empty records with the previous step.
After filling the above value where ever I found the Exception Start and Exception End would like to fill with the above value.
Please refer blow step2 and Step3 as examples output.

```
+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|   No    |          Date          |        ProcessStep         |           Step2            |           Step3            |
+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 643995G | 03/12/2012 3:22:48 PM  | TransferInStart            | TransferInStart            | TransferInStart            |
| 643995G | 03/12/2012 3:22:50 PM  |                            | TransferInStart            | TransferInStart            |
| 643995G | 15/02/2013 10:53:57 AM | Hold                       | Hold                       | Hold                       |
| 643995G | 15/02/2013 10:54:00 AM | Hold Copy Processing Start | Hold Copy Processing Start | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 20/02/2013 4:38:26 PM  |                            | Hold Copy Processing Start | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 21/02/2013 3:27:01 PM  | ExceptionStart             | ExceptionStart             | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 9:38:32 AM  | ExceptionEnd               | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 9:39:32 AM  |                            | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 10:04:53 AM |                            | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 22/02/2013 10:04:56 AM |                            | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 25/02/2013 10:48:18 AM | TransferIn                 | TransferIn                 | TransferIn                 |
| 643995G | 25/02/2013 10:48:19 AM | CatalougingStart           | CatalougingStart           | CatalougingStart           |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 1:59:44 PM  |                            | CatalougingStart           | CatalougingStart           |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 1:59:45 PM  |                            | CatalougingStart           | CatalougingStart           |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 2:05:01 PM  | Catalouging                | Catalouging                | Catalouging                |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 2:05:02 PM  | ProcessingStart            | ProcessingStart            | ProcessingStart            |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 6:09:51 PM  |                            | ProcessingStart            | ProcessingStart            |
| 643995G | 27/02/2013 6:09:52 PM  |                            | ProcessingStart            | ProcessingStart            |
| 643995G | 04/03/2013 2:03:16 PM  |                            | ProcessingStart            | ProcessingStart            |
| 643995G | 04/03/2013 2:03:17 PM  | Hold Copy Processing Start | Hold Copy Processing Start | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 11/03/2013 2:27:14 PM  |                            | Hold Copy Processing Start | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:09:55 AM | ExceptionStart             | ExceptionStart             | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:10:27 AM | ExceptionEnd               | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:10:52 AM |                            | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:11:27 AM |                            | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:28:37 AM |                            | ExceptionEnd               | Hold Copy Processing Start |
| 643995G | 12/03/2013 10:46:21 AM | Processing                 | Processing                 | Processing                 |
+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O7O1.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndwbP.png)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Different databases have different ways of solving this problem.  One method uses a correlated subquery in a `select`.  A typical method can be expressed in ANSI standard SQL as:

```
update t
     set step2 = (select t2.processstep
                  from t t2
                  where t2.no = t.no and
                        t2.date <= t.date and
                        t2.processstep is not null
                  order by date desc
                  fetch first 1 row only
                 );
```

In some databases, you would use `limit` or `top` to get the first row.  Even so, this might not work in all databases, but something similar is likely to work.